# Customizing theme - where is the purple background set?

Tags: 20.04, themes, gnome-shell, gdm

I've customized my GDM theme and Gnome Shell theme in Ubuntu 20.04 (using Yaru as the base).
To do this I have modified both `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource` and the files in `/usr/share/themes` for my new theme.
My GDM screen background is the color I have specified, and the GDM, Gnome Shell, and Desktop themes are exactly as I want them.

*However*, when I log in, I see a purple screen for about a second, just before my desktop wallpaper is displayed.

This is the sequence of steps:

1. I type my password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the GDM login screen:
2. I briefly see a dark (black) background
3. **Then I briefly see this purple background**
4. The desktop "expands" to cover the purple background.
5. Then I see the full desktop (top bar, dock, and the wallpaper)

I've investigated both `gdm3.css` and `gnome-shell.css` and I did not see references to shades of purple or aubergine (either as hex or rgb values) in my modified files.

Does anyone know where this brief purple background color is coming from, so I can change/fix it?

---

Screenshots showing the sequence of steps:

(1) GDM Screen...
[image]

(2) Dark (black) background...
[image]

(3) Purple background...
[image]

(4) Desktop "expanding"...
[image]

(5) Desktop...
[image]

Comment: You can use a extension for that. Is it Ok to use extension?

Comment: You mean the User Themes extension? I don't want to use that, since I am already able to create and use a custom theme without  that. Is there another extension you have in mind?

Comment: Yes.. "good bye gdm3" gnome shell extension. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3037/good-bye-gdm-flick/

Comment: I'll try this extensions and let you know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but it's not quite what I am looking for. I see what the extension does: it eliminates the "zoom" effect, shown in my 3rd screen shot, where the desktop "expands" to fill the entire screen. When this extension is enabled, the desktop just appears, so the purple background is never shown. However, I'd like to find where this background color is actually set.

Comment: By the way, when this extension was installed/enabled, my Night Light did not work. I removed the extension, and Night Light is working. I'm not sure if this was a "glitch" on my system, or if the extension caused it.

Comment: Night Light on GDM screen is not effected by this extension. I understand your above point. I will see if I can help.