# Smooth transition between lock screen and Home

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, animations

Is there any way to make a transition between the lock screen and Home more smooth?

- Current: I log in --> blank page --> purple background loaded --> Home comes out
- What I want: I log in --> animation --> Home (similar to unlocking phone)

---

- lock screen: The screen before logging in
- Home: The page that is shown after logging in / where you can view trash, top bar, dock, windows, ... (I'm not sure if this is called "Home")

Comment: I was thinking if the purple background could be changed to a different color (sames as your "blank page") this might make the visual shifts seem less noticeable. For reference, see my (so far unanswered) question [Customizing theme - where is the purple background set?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1332130/100356). However, someone suggested using [Good Bye GDM3 Login Screen to Desktop Flick for gnome-shell 3.36 Only!](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3037/good-bye-gdm-flick/). This extension was not what I had wanted, but you may find it useful.

Comment: You need to realize that there may be 2 different interfaces involved in your question. 1.) The **initial login (the purple one)**, is being presented by **GDM(3)**. 2.) The other one is the simple, in-session lock screen, that you normally get by pressing the "super key"+L combo. This lightweight in-session lock screen is provided by **gnome-shell**. These two interfaces may need different approaches (I guess). Also: by "Home", do you mean the normal logged-in "Desktop"?